# PowerShell bad syntax, it is not compiling

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls
systeminfo | find /i "System Type" | find /i "X86-based PC"
if %errorlevel% == 0 set spth="C:\Program Files\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\Shoretel.exe"
Echo Checking System Type (x86 vs x64)
systeminfo | find /i "System Type" | find /i "X64-based PC"
if %errorlevel% == 0 set spth="C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\Shoretel.exe"

Echo Checking if Communicator is already installed.....
if exist %spth% goto end1
if NOT exist %spth% goto install

:install
echo Installing Shoretel Communicator
\\cupe-fs-1\apps\ShortelConnect\install-win\GPO\setup.exe /S /v"/qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
echo Installation Finished
exit

:end1
echo Shoretel Communicator is already installed.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul
exit
```

[powershell error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHx4u.png)

Comment: That code is not powershell, it's a bat script (and doesn't seem to invoke powershell). Are you trying to invoke this script as a powershell script?

Comment: yes zdan! I am doing an internship and I am supposed to help but I am so lost I though some of this code does not even have () and yeah. Could you please help me make this work and I will try my best to do the rest of the scripts. Please I need a little push!

Comment: The code works, although I would probably speed up the process and not invoke systeminfo. I think what @zdan is trying to tell you is that you are trying to start the file in an incorrect way. If I start this under cmd there is no problem what so ever. Do you intend to create a powershell script of this batch script?

Answer (score 1):

I trimmed out the systeminfo parts to make it faster to run just so you can see what I meant with my comment above. I also removed the extra output that is unlikely to be seen anyway.

```
@echo off
cls
if exist "C:\Program Files\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\Shoretel.exe" goto end
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\Shoretel.exe" goto end

echo Installing Shoretel Communicator
\\cupe-fs-1\apps\ShortelConnect\install-win\GPO\setup.exe /S /v"/qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"

:end
```